# Array value missing after a for loop C

Tags: c

I'm new to C and I have a problem with this code that I made that is supposed to take in a string and a delimiter and split string and put them into a list. I have tried to print the characters one by one and it works (shows HelloWorld) but for some reason it doesn't get stored after the loop has finished. Can anyone please help?

Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *string = "Hello World";
    char delimiter = ' ';
    char **strings_list = malloc(sizeof(string) + 1);
    int word = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(string); i++)
    {
        if (string[i] == delimiter)
        {
            word++;
        }
        else
        {
            strings_list[word][i] = string[i];
        }
    }

    printf("%s", strings_list[0]);
    free(strings_list);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because `string` is a pointer, its size will be the size of *the pointer itself* and not what it might point to. Use `strlen` to get the length of a null-terminated string.

Comment: You also have other problems, like using the uninitialized pointers in `strings_list[word] `. You might need to spend more time with your text-books and read more about strings and pointers.

Comment: `<=` should be `<`

Comment: You're never adding null terminators to the strings.

Comment: `sizeof` would be correct if you declared it `char string[] = "Hello World";`, but then you don't need to add 1 because the size includes the null terminator.

Comment: But if `strings_list` is to hold N char *, you need to `malloc(N * sizeof *strings_list)`.

Answer (score 0):

The issues found in your code are

1. Use `strlen` to get the length of a null-terminated string
2. Instead of `i <= strlen(string)` use `i < strlen(string)`
3. Allocate memory for each items in string
4. Free complete memory.

Below is the updated code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* for malloc & free*/

int main()
{
    char *string = "Hello World";
    char delimiter = ' ';
    char **strings_list;
    int word = 0;
    int maxelementsinword = 6; /* Max size of a word - here its 5 + 1 Null char */
    int maxitemsinlist = 2;  /* Num of items in list - here its 2 */
    int j = 0;

    strings_list = malloc(maxitemsinlist * sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < maxitemsinlist; i++)
        strings_list[i] = malloc((maxelementsinword+1) * sizeof(char)); /* sizeof(char) is 1, but to make it clear */
        
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)
    {
        if (string[i] == delimiter)
        {
            strings_list[word][j] = '\0'; /* Null terminate the string */
            word++;
            j = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            strings_list[word][j] = string[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < maxitemsinlist; i++)
    {
        printf("\n %s", strings_list[i]);
        free(strings_list[i]); /* Free the items in list*/
    }

    free(strings_list); /* free list*/
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you null terminate the strings?